# dynamic threshold values in highchart - arearange

Tags: highcharts, threshold

I have a highchart of type `"arearange"` line, such like

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/arearange-line/

I want to use negative color for line, whenever the line is going beyond (or crossing) the range value. To achive this we can use `"threshold"` in `"series"` attribute, but my problem is, i do not have a single threshold value, when ever the line crosses the range value, i want to plot the line in negative color.

Below is the sample code can be executed in above fiddle link. Where i mentioned few values (for example) to be plotted in negative color, which is indicated in below code with command line ("Here i want a negative color").

```
$(function () {

    var ranges = [
            [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
            [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
            [1246579200000, 15.5, 29.6],
            [1246665600000, 16.7, 30.7],
            [1246752000000, 16.5, 25.0],
            [1246838400000, 17.8, 25.7],
            [1246924800000, 13.5, 24.8],
            [1247011200000, 10.5, 21.4],
            [1247097600000, 9.2, 23.8],
            [1247184000000, 11.6, 21.8],
            [1247270400000, 10.7, 23.7],
            [1247356800000, 11.0, 23.3],
            [1247443200000, 11.6, 23.7],
            [1247529600000, 11.8, 20.7],
            [1247616000000, 12.6, 22.4],
            [1247702400000, 13.6, 19.6],
            [1247788800000, 11.4, 22.6],
            [1247875200000, 13.2, 25.0],
            [1247961600000, 14.2, 21.6],
            [1248048000000, 13.1, 17.1],
            [1248134400000, 12.2, 15.5],
            [1248220800000, 12.0, 20.8],
            [1248307200000, 12.0, 17.1],
            [1248393600000, 12.7, 18.3],
            [1248480000000, 12.4, 19.4],
            [1248566400000, 12.6, 19.9],
            [1248652800000, 11.9, 20.2],
            [1248739200000, 11.0, 19.3],
            [1248825600000, 10.8, 17.8],
            [1248912000000, 11.8, 18.5],
            [1248998400000, 10.8, 16.1]
        ],
        averages = [
            [1246406400000, 81.5],**//Here i want a negative color**
            [1246492800000, 22.1],
            [1246579200000, 3], **//Here i want a negative color**
            [1246665600000, 23.8],
            [1246752000000, 21.4],
            [1246838400000, 21.3],
            [1246924800000, 18.3],
            [1247011200000, 15.4],
            [1247097600000, 16.4],
            [1247184000000, 17.7],
            [1247270400000, 17.5],
            [1247356800000, 17.6],
            [1247443200000, 17.7],
            [1247529600000, 16.8],
            [1247616000000, 17.7],
            [1247702400000, 16.3],
            [1247788800000, 17.8],
            [1247875200000, 18.1],
            [1247961600000, 17.2],
            [1248048000000, 14.4],
            [1248134400000, 13.7],
            [1248220800000, 15.7],
            [1248307200000, 34.6],**//Here i want a negative color**
            [1248393600000, -15.3],
            [1248480000000, 15.3],
            [1248566400000, 15.8],
            [1248652800000, 15.2],
            [1248739200000, 14.8],
            [1248825600000, 14.4],
            [1248912000000, 15],
            [1248998400000, 90.6] `//Here i want a negative color`
        ];


    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
            text: 'July temperatures'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        legend: {
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: averages,
            zIndex: 1,
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'white',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Range',
            data: ranges,
            type: 'arearange',
            lineWidth: 0,
            linkedTo: ':previous',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            zIndex: 0
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: How should a negative point be colored? Should it color its marker, line connecting the next point, previous point or both points? The whole line or only part of it which is above/under the area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zones or multicolor series plugin can give you expected effect. You can also find the answer to your question here, at the official Highcharts forum: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/arearange-dynamic-threshold-value-change-color-t37236/.

```
$(function() {
  var ranges = [
      [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
      [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
      [1246579200000, 15.5, 29.6],
      [1246665600000, 16.7, 30.7],
      [1246752000000, 16.5, 25.0],
      [1246838400000, 17.8, 25.7],
      [1246924800000, 13.5, 24.8],
      [1247011200000, 10.5, 21.4],
      [1247097600000, 9.2, 23.8],
      [1247184000000, 11.6, 21.8],
      [1247270400000, 10.7, 23.7],
      [1247356800000, 11.0, 23.3],
      [1247443200000, 11.6, 23.7],
      [1247529600000, 11.8, 20.7],
      [1247616000000, 12.6, 22.4],
      [1247702400000, 13.6, 19.6],
      [1247788800000, 11.4, 22.6],
      [1247875200000, 13.2, 25.0],
      [1247961600000, 14.2, 21.6],
      [1248048000000, 13.1, 17.1],
      [1248134400000, 12.2, 15.5],
      [1248220800000, 12.0, 20.8],
      [1248307200000, 12.0, 17.1],
      [1248393600000, 12.7, 18.3],
      [1248480000000, 12.4, 19.4],
      [1248566400000, 12.6, 19.9],
      [1248652800000, 11.9, 20.2],
      [1248739200000, 11.0, 19.3],
      [1248825600000, 10.8, 17.8],
      [1248912000000, 11.8, 18.5],
      [1248998400000, 10.8, 16.1]
    ],
    averages = [{
        x: 1246406400000,
        y: 81.5,
        segmentColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
        marker: {
          fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
        }
      },
      [1246492800000, 22.1],
      [1246579200000, 23],
      [1246665600000, 23.8],
      [1246752000000, 21.4],
      [1246838400000, 21.3],
      [1246924800000, 18.3],
      [1247011200000, 15.4],
      [1247097600000, 16.4],
      [1247184000000, 17.7], {
        x: 1247270400000,
        y: 17.5,
        segmentColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
      }, {
        x: 1247356800000,
        y: 77.6,
        segmentColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
        marker: {
          fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
        }
      },
      [1247443200000, 17.7],
      [1247529600000, 16.8],
      [1247616000000, 17.7],
      [1247702400000, 16.3],
      [1247788800000, 17.8],
      [1247875200000, 18.1],
      [1247961600000, 17.2],
      [1248048000000, 14.4],
      [1248134400000, 13.7],
      [1248220800000, 15.7], {
        x: 1248307200000,
        y: 14.6,
        segmentColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
      }, {
        x: 1248393600000,
        y: -5,
        segmentColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
        marker: {
          fillColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
        }
      },
      [1248480000000, 15.3],
      [1248566400000, 15.8],
      [1248652800000, 15.2],
      [1248739200000, 14.8],
      [1248825600000, 14.4],
      [1248912000000, 15],
      [1248998400000, 13.6]
    ];

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
      text: 'July temperatures'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: null
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      crosshairs: true,
      shared: true,
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Temperature',
      data: averages,
      type: 'coloredline',
      zIndex: 1,
    }, {
      name: 'Range',
      data: ranges,
      type: 'arearange',
      lineWidth: 0,
      linkedTo: ':previous',
      color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      zIndex: 0
    }]
  });
});
```

API Reference:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.zones

Examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/k1bL3umw/ - using zones

http://jsfiddle.net/q0uh8z34/ - using multi color series plugin